# Determining the existence of a limit from a value

Tags: calculus, limits

In studying for my exam I am going over past exam problems and have come across a snag.

The problem in question is as follows: The statement: "The existence of $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ depends on the value of $f(a)$."

(a) is sometimes true
(b) is always true
(c) is never true

I believe the correct answer is "(a) is sometimes true" because there are situations where it is possible to have a function such as a piece wise function that has a point that is defined on the graph at $f(a)$ but is not continuous with the rest of the function. However, you can also have a continuous function such as $y=x$ where $f(a)$ is continuous and defined.

Would this be the correct logic for choosing my answer, or am I incorrect altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: never true.

The definition of a limit is as follows:

We say that a function $f$ has a limit $l$ as $x \rightarrow a$ if:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \ \exists \ \delta > 0: \ 0 < |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - l| < \epsilon$$

$f(a)$ has nothing to do with that whatsoever.

Comment: Ah. I usually forget to go back to the basics like this and instead end up trying to figure out my questions in a relatively convoluted manner. It just confuses me. I appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

is never true. look at $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x = 1.$$  has the value you assign to $\frac{\sin x}x$ at $x = 0$ any influence on the limit?